# How can I use VBScript to extract only the last line from a string

Tags: vbscript

Here is a sample of a comment log:

```
5/20/2010 12:48:56 PM Revision 1 AFR Started Quick Change: Imported document 
5/25/2010 2:13:52 PM Revision 1 AFR Released:  
6/9/2010 9:56:58 AM Revision 1 JKF Start Change:  
6/9/2010 9:57:39 AM Revision 2 JKF Released: ADDED GUSSET FOR 0050 BRACKET 
6/18/2010 11:32:39 AM Revision 2 JKF Start Change:  
6/18/2010 11:33:17 AM Revision 3 JKF Released: CHANGED GUSSET TO 12GA 
8/24/2010 2:17:07 PM Revision 3 AFR Start Change:  
8/24/2010 2:17:27 PM Revision 4 AFR Released:  
1/6/2011 2:56:46 PM Revision 4 JKF Start Change:  
1/6/2011 3:01:26 PM Revision 5 JKF Released: Updated SS brackets out of bar stock per guy n.
11/30/2011 9:29:30 AM Revision 5 TJB Start Change:  
12/2/2011 1:25:00 PM Revision 6 TJB Released: updated block names & holes 
12/12/2011 4:01:10 PM Revision 6 ADH Start Change:  
12/13/2011 9:20:34 AM Revision 7 ADH Released:  
12/13/2011 9:20:46 AM Revision 7 ADH Start Change:  
12/13/2011 9:21:27 AM Revision 8 ADH Released:  
1/4/2012 2:59:57 PM Revision 8 AFR Start Change:  
1/11/2012 10:28:36 AM Revision 9 AFR Released: UPDATED BLOCK NAMES 
9/13/2012 1:35:50 PM Revision 9 ADH Start Change:  
9/13/2012 1:41:02 PM Revision 10 ADH Released:  
4/5/2013 1:46:39 PM Revision 10 TJB Start Change: UPDATED DESCRIPTIONS 
4/5/2013 1:47:18 PM Revision 11 TJB Revoked Workflow
6/13/2013 8:25:26 AM Revision 10 AFR Start Change:  
8/23/2013 7:48:07 AM JKF Changed manager to JKF 
8/23/2013 7:48:17 AM Revision 11 JKF Forwarded to JKF:  
8/23/2013 8:43:11 AM Revision 11 JKF Released: Changed Paint color to Stardust Silver 
10/11/2013 5:57:26 PM Revision 11 JMS Start Change: UPDATING PAINT TYPE 
10/11/2013 6:01:19 PM Revision 12 JMS Released: UPDATED SS PAINT TYPE TO NO 
11/15/2013 1:32:46 PM Revision 12 ALH Start Change:  
11/15/2013 1:33:59 PM Revision 13 ALH Forwarded to TTM:  
11/19/2013 2:50:43 PM Revision 13 TTM Released:  
12/17/2013 2:09:29 PM Revision 13 TTM Start Change: 
12/30/2013 9:06:48 AM Revision 14 TTM Released:  
4/23/2014 8:47:31 AM Revision 14 DSW Retired:  
4/23/2014 9:00:42 AM Revision 14 DSW Unretired:  
6/30/2014 12:57:48 PM Revision 14 JTZ Start Change: 
6/30/2014 1:16:22 PM Revision 15 JTZ Released:  7
/17/2014 7:27:11 AM Revision 15 JTZ Start Change:  
7/17/2014 7:30:43 AM Revision 16 JTZ Released:  
9/9/2014 8:12:56 AM Revision 16 AFR Start Change:  
9/9/2014 8:22:05 AM Revision 17 AFR Released: CHANGED PART NUMBERS ON FLAT BRACKETS 
9/17/2014 7:37:02 AM Revision 17 TMS Start Change:  
9/17/2014 7:50:36 AM Revision 18 TMS Released: CREATED 3 NEW BLOCKS TO SEPERATE NEW BRACKETS FROM OLD BRACKETS.  ERASED UN-NEEDED BEND LINES FROM NEW
BRACKETS.  
9/17/2014 8:03:03 AM Revision 19 DSW Started Quick Change: 
9/17/2014 8:06:45 AM Revision 19 DSW Released: Fixed part number on pull slips for new flat brackets 9/17/2014 8:58:18 AM Revision 19 TMS Start Change:  
9/17/2014 9:00:07 AM Revision 20 TMS Released: no change
9/17/2014 9:26:10 AM Revision 20 TMS Start Change:  
9/17/2014 9:26:46 AM Revision 21 TMS Released: no chnage.  test open for IT.
```

Currently every time a document is changed an email notification is sent out to managers and it contains this entire log.  Is there a way that I can only send the last entry in the log?  Thanks in advance for any ideas.

In case it is hard to read, each line starts with the date.

Comment: It all looks like a single line anyway!

Answer (score 3):

If your log is being read from a a file, then you'll want to do something like this:

```
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
  strLine = objFile.ReadLine
  If objFile.atEndOfStream Then
    strLastLine = strLine
  End If
Loop
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: No need for the `If` statement. `strLine` will hold the last line.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot more sense than how I had been looking at it.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Just split the array and get the last item in the array.

```
dim str
dim arr

str = "string\nseperated\nby\nnewlines"
arr = Split(str, "\n")

WScript.Echo arr(UBound(arr))
```

Comment: This approach is problematic for large files, because the computer has to read the entire file into memory for this to work. For large files this will likely lead to heavy swapping, thus slowing the computer to a crawl.

Comment: Agreed it is a waste of effort to read the whole file into an array but it seems like the only way to do it with VB Script: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/08/12/can-i-read-a-text-file-from-the-bottom-up.aspx